# How to run Hadoop utils on Dataproc cluster programmatically?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc

I have:

- App Engine application (Java/Python)
- Dataproc cluster

I want to run one of the Hadoop utils on master node (`hadoop distcp`) programatically. What is the best way to do that? So far I have the next clue: ssh to master node and run util from there. Is there any other option to accomplish the same goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To run DistCp you can submit regular [Hadoop MR job through Dataproc API or gcloud](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/jobs/submit/hadoop) and specify `org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp` as a main class:

```sh
gcloud dataproc jobs submit hadoop --cluster=<CLUSTER> \
    --class=org.apache.hadoop.tools.DistCp -- <SRC> <DST>
```

From Python you can use either [REST API](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects.regions.jobs/submit) directly or [Python Client library](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-python/latest/dataproc/gapic/v1/api.html#google.cloud.dataproc_v1.JobControllerClient.submit_job) to submit DistCp job.